# Condensing a Select's several returned characters into a single string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Simply put, I have a select that will return multiple single characters, and thus won't work. Is there any way to bunch all the single characters into a single returnable string?

My current slow and ugly solution:

```
,'('+(Select Left(max(AE_D1),1) 
        FROM ACCESS_EVENTS
      WHERE LEFT(AE_D1,1) like 'W'
        AND replace(HR.firstname,' ','')+' '+replace(HR.lastname, ' ','') LIKE Left(AE_D2,len(replace(HR.firstname,' ','')+' '+replace(HR.lastname, ' ','')))) +')'
+'('+(Select Left(max(AE_D1),1) 
        FROM ACCESS_EVENTS
       WHERE LEFT(AE_D1,1) like 'M'
         AND replace(HR.firstname,' ','')+' '+replace(HR.lastname, ' ','') LIKE Left(AE_D2,len(replace(HR.firstname,' ','')+' '+replace(HR.lastname, ' ','')))) +')'
```

. . . Repeat until all cases are covered . . .

EDIT - Extra information: Each 'W' or 'M' is the first character of an access event's name, related to where the event took place. There are about 9 different event characters to cover. The point of the query is to show when a person has events from more than one area associated to their name. The problem now is just to display it cleanly.

Comment: All that string manipulation renders indexes unusable, which is why data should not be stored like that...

Comment: Yes, the HR table has _much_ to be desired. However, I'm not in any position to fix it. :(

Comment: What are the cases you are looking for?

Comment: You should be able to fix this query, but we have only have a snapshot of what you are looking for.  Can you give more info on what some of the source data looks like and what you want the final result to look like?  We may be able to do 1 query that is indexable.

Comment: The goal is to produce something like  
  
Employee Name | Employee Terminal | Event Terminal  
John Doe      |  Winnipeg         |   (W)(C)(M)  

This would be an employee who's 'home' terminal would be Winnipeg, but has access events from them at other terminals.

To get employee terminal and event terminal information two tables are referenced 'HR' for name and terminal and 'ACCESS_EVENTS' for access event and location of the event. HR lacks any index column, hence the hacking together of names.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to read [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

Comment: Thank you very much. That was an excellent source of examples and different methods of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could an indexed view work for your desired data?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx#XSLTsection124121120120

Comment: I don't know, I don't really have much experience with more advanced sql actions.